# I want shell to load bash_profile

Tags: ansible

I want to load bash_profile when executing commands with ansible shell.

When I examine it, I write it on the net that it is enough to write the following setting in ansible.cfg.

```
[defaults]
executable = /bin/bash -l
```

However, the following errors occurred when executed.

```
{"changed": false, "cmd": "'/bin/bash -l' -c '~~~'", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

Perhaps it seems that it is recognized as "bin / bash - l" command.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `executable = /bin/bash` without the `-l`

Use also the environment variable under your task:

```
  environment:
      HOME: /home/username
```

Comment: Thank you reply.However, this method did not go through bash_profile.

Comment: To go through the bash profile, use `source /home/username/.bash_profile` while calling your shell command

Comment: Thank you reply.In this method bash_profile was not running. So it was made to load by executing like ```source /home/username/.bash_profile && my_command```.Thank you.